# Python - live update graphs; with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

everyone. I meet with a problem to make a live updating animation. Here I have an **age.csv file** as below, which has three columns. The last two columns (Age & Child) change with the first column (Year), so I want to make an animation.

```
Year  Age  Child
2011  50     1
2012  60     2
2013  55     3
2014  35     6
2015  45     4
2016  75     7
```

The final effect should look like this animation on the webpage:

(You can scroll down to look at 'the temperature over time' movie. I didn't use their codes, so their codes are irrelevant with this question. )

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/graph-sensor-data-with-python-and-matplotlib/update-a-graph-in-real-time

**Here is  the code created by myself**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

list_year=[]
list_age=[]
list_child=[]

def animate(i):
    with open('age.csv','r') as f:
        next(f) # skip header

        for row in f:
            year,age,child = (s.strip() for s in row.split(','))
            list_year.append(year)
            list_age.append(int(age))
            list_child.append(int(child))

        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(list_year,list_age)
        ax.plot(list_year,list_child)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,interval=1000) 
anim.save('livetime.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

**However, although I finally got the following figure to show the changes, it's definitely not the gif animation I was expected.**

[The figure I got as a failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es7qw.png)

**After checking the codes many times, I still failed and didn't find any errors, so I am appreciate it if you can figure out what's the problem. Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are rendering all of the data every frame of animation. You need to process one line of input data every time the `animate` function is called. The easiest way to do this is probably to create a list of lines from the input file and index the list, like this:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

list_year=[]
list_age=[]
list_child=[]
lines = []

def animate(i):

    year,age,child = (s.strip() for s in lines[i].split(','))
    list_year.append(year)
    list_age.append(int(age))
    list_child.append(int(child))

    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(list_year,list_age)
    ax.plot(list_year,list_child)

with open(os.path.join(os.path.realpath('.'), 'src/test/age.csv'),'r') as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    lines = f.readlines()

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, frames=len(lines)) 

anim.save(os.path.join(os.path.realpath('.'), 'src/test/livetime.gif'), writer='imagemagick')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I will try your codes and see if it works!!!!

Comment: It works!!!! I can't express how glad I am!!! I am really grateful to you!